# Is it possible to get some type of performance report on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, performance, monitoring, reporting

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2 and I would like to know how well it handles a certain load.

Is there any built in way of telling the server to monitor performance for a specific period and then produce some sort of report conveying the load on CPU, ram, disk etc.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a pretty straight forward request; check out the performance monitor built into server 2008

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749249.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Opmanager is free for up to 10 devices and works well with 2008 R2 performance monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned bei Univ426, Windows Performance Monitor is the most obvious choice. You can set it up to record performance data over time. If you prefer working through the command line you can use [Logman](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753820(v=ws.11).aspx) to control data collection.

There are also plenty of other performance monitoring tools. Too many to list them all here, but I have compiled an overview: https://checkpanel.com/resources/windows-server-performance-monitoring-tools